# onclick not firing from laptop mousepad 'tap/touch', working with LEFT click of mousepad

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, onclick

Hi Sorry if this sounds confusing but I have an issue involving the 'onclick' event of a dropdown list li> elements. The onclick function specified works correctly when clicking the mouse LEFT button, but when I use my laptop and 'tap' the mousepad to click instead of using the LEFT mousepad button the onclick even does not fire?
I create the list via a for loop and then add to the ul> elements html

```
for (var i = 0; i < accountListData.length; i++) {
                        if(accountListData[i]['ACCOUNTCODE'].toUpperCase().trim().includes(txt.toUpperCase().trim()) || accountListData[i]['ACCOUNTNAME'].toUpperCase().trim().includes(txt.toUpperCase().trim())) {
                            s += '<li onclick="selectAccount(this, ' + "'" + accountListData[i]['UseRatesFromAccount'].trim() + "'," + "'" + accountListData[i]['ACCOUNTNAME'].replaceAll("'", "").trim() + "'," + "'" + accountListData[i]['subAccounts'] + "'," + "'" + accountListData[i]['ACCOUNTCODE'] + "'" + ')" class="account-quick-search-item" value="' + accountListData[i]['ACCOUNTCODE'] + '">' + '<div style="' + 'font-size: 11px;font-weight: bolder;">' + accountListData[i]["ACCOUNTCODE"] + '</div><div style="' + 'margin-left: 6px; margin-top: 2px;' + '">' + accountListData[i]["ACCOUNTNAME"] + '</div>';
                            if (accountListData[i]['subAccounts'] == "1") {
                                s = s + '<div class="sub-account-icon"></div>' + '</li>';
                            }
                            else {
                                s = s + '</li>'
                            }
                            if (i != (accountListData.length - 1)) {
                                s += '<li class="account-quick-search-divider"></li>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $("#accountsQuickSearch").html(s);
```

Any help would be appreciated, is the mousepad/touchpad of a laptop a different type of click event for the 'tap' type of click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel silly, I have found the solution by swapping out 'onclick' for 'onmousedown' event instead, which seems to fire no matter which of the mouse buttons is pressed

Comment: If you found out what the issue was and this describes the solution please mark this answer as the solution.

Comment: hi my apologies, I did try to mark as answered but got hit with the its to soon to answer your own question @AztecCodes